# Python String Match with respective index

Tags: python

```
str1 = ['106.51.107.185', '122.169.20.139', '123.201.53.226']
str2 = ['106.51.107.185', '122.169.20.138', '123.201.53.226']
```

I need to match the above string based on their respective Index.

str1[0] match str2[0]

str1[1] match str2[1]

str1[2] match str2[2]

based on the match i need the output.

I tried from my end, between the 2 strings, str[0] is checking the match with str2[:], it need to match only with the respective indexes alone. Please assist.

Thanks !!!

Comment: What should be the output here? `[True, False, True]`?

Comment: Hello Willem, I am looking for the non-match index and match index  output separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a simple solution using `for` loop:

```
res = []
for i in range(len(str1)):
    res.append(str1[i] == str2[i])
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[True, False, True]
```

One can also use `list comprehension` for this:

```
res = [ (str1[i] == str2[i])     for i in range(len(str1)) ]
```

Edit: to get indexes of matched and non-matched:

```
matched = []
non_matched = []
for i in range(len(str1)):
    if str1[i] == str2[i]:
        matched.append(i)
    else:
        non_matched.append(i)
print("matched:",matched)
print("non-matched:", non_matched)
```

Output:

```
matched: [0, 2]
non-matched: [1]
```

Comment: i am getting error when run this.                                                                                                                          Error: "res.append(ip(i)==outer(i))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: What are `ip` and `outer`? They are not part of this question. You should not deviate from the question. You may post another question giving details of `ip` and `outer`.

Comment: sry for that, ip is str1, outer is str2. I am using ip and outer while running.

Comment: I am getting the expected result which you posted initially. Instead for true or false, need the not matched index as result

Comment: I have added code to get list of matched and non-matched items in my answer above. You should should accept it by clicking on the checkmark on the left side if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 6):

## Truth values

You can use:

```
from operator import eq

map(eq, str1, str2)
```

This will produce an iterable of booleans (`True` or `False`) in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), and a list of booleans in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x). In case you want a list in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), you can use the `list(..)` construct over the `map(..)`:

```
from operator import eq

list(map(eq, str1, str2))
```

This works since `map` takes as first argument a function (here `eq` from the `operator` package), and one or more iterables). It will then call that function on the arguments of the iterables (so the first item of `str1` and `str2`, then the second item of `str1` and `str2`, and so on). The outcome of that function call is yielded.

## Indices

Alternatively, we can use list comprehension, to get the indices, for example:

```
same_indices = [i for i, (x, y) for enumerate(zip(str1, str2)) if x == y]
```

or the different ones:

```
diff_indices = [i for i, (x, y) for enumerate(zip(str1, str2)) if x != y]
```

We can also reuse the above `map` result with:

```
from operator import eq, itemgetter

are_same = map(eq, str1, str2)

same_indices = map(itemgetter(0),
                   filter(itemgetter(1), enumerate(are_same))
                  )
```

If we then convert `same_indices` to a list, we get:

```
>>> list(same_indices)
[0, 2]
```

We can also perform such construct on `are_diff`:

```
from operator import ne, itemgetter

are_diff = map(ne, str1, str2)

diff_indices = map(itemgetter(0),
                   filter(itemgetter(1), enumerate(are_diff))
                  )
```

Comment: I get error :           map(eq(ip, outer))
TypeError: map() requires at least two args

Comment: @selvamsamymuthu: it is *not*, `map(eq(str1, str2))`, but `map(eq, str1, str2)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip and list comprehension i.e

```
[i==j for i,j in zip(str1,str2)]

[True, False, True]
```

Comment: Thanks!!!, I need the output which is matched and which is not matched.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact output you need but, if you want to compare those two lists and get the difference between them you can convert them to set then subtract them as follows:

```
st = str(set(str1) - set(str2))
```